# How to reduce the model size while creating own model with our own data in deepspeech?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create my own model with own data in deepspeech. At the time of exporting model the model size remains same with the existing model. Everything is working fine and model has been trained and exported. But the exported file `output_graph.pb` file size remains the same size as deepspeech pre-trained model size 188.9mb.

I don’t know whether my training files have been concatenated with the pre-trained models.

**command i have used to export model:-**

```
python3 DeepSpeech.py --epochs 1 --train_files ./train.csv --dev_files ./dev.csv --test_files ./test.csv --use_allow_growth true --export_dir ./kavyadata/
```

Please clarify and let me know the proper command to export model with my own data.